# How do I put this into one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapp

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in winapps.list_installed(): 
           print(item, file=f)
```

So I have this basic code. How could I make it into line? without including the with open, as other stuff is included later on.

I was thinking something like this xD

```
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in winapps.list_installed(print(item, file=f))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do the same thing with one line of code?

Comment: readability first, why are you trying to do it with oneliner?

Comment: tbh because i am new to python and wanted to see how its done :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be put into one line in several ways. Without changing your code you could just remove the newline and indent:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in winapps.list_installed(): print(item, file=f)
```

Or just using unpacking and print formatting:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(*winapps.list_installed(), sep="\n", file=f)
```

Which can also be done in one line:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f: print(*winapps.list_installed(), sep="\n", file=f)
```

That said, this is not a good code design choice. Making things more conscience can (at times) make it less readable.